# BIOS issue after installing a new CPU AMD FX-8320

Tags: motherboard, bios

The specification of my desktop computer is as

**Processor**: AMD FX 8320, **Motherboard**: Asus M5A97, **RAM**: Kingston HyperX 16 GB (8*2), **HD**: 1TB WD Black, **Graphics Card**: 2GB Saphire 5450, **SMPS**: Cooler Master 650W, **OS**: Windows 10 64-bit

The motherboard is 3yrs old and its BIOS is updated and latest as per the [link](https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/M5A97/HelpDesk_Download/). According to this link, the latest BIOS version for Windows 10 64-bit is 1605 released on 2012/10/31 with size of 2.29 Mbytes.
I already updated BIOS of my motherboard about two years ago. Currently its version is 1605.

The processor on the motherboard was AMD FX-8320. There was heating issue in the processor. That's why AMD replaced it. And new processor (AMD FX-8320) installed. After installing new processor, following issue started:

“**New CPU installed! Please enter setup to configure your system. Press F1 to Run SETUP**”

After pressing **F1**, I press **F8** for Boot Menu, then I select **P3:WDC..**

Then I see the Windows login screen.

Pls find the enclosed images.
After every restart, I need to follow these steps after pressing **F1**.

I replaced on-board 3V battery (CMOS Battery) but issue not resolved.

My motherboard is not in the warranty now. That's why the service center is not ready to listen/discuss/talk anything.

I would request you to guide me for other troubleshooting steps.

Regards

Smith

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Is it because of CMOS Battery issue?" - It could be.  Have you tried to replace the battery?  I assume you updated the firmware before you installed the new CPU.

Comment: After you press F1, are you entering the BIOS/UEFI setup utility, and then are you saving the settings before continuing? That is usually all that is required to store the current settings permanently.

Comment: Ramhound I didn't change CMOS battery yet. As you said, firmware update before CPU installation, motherboard firmware was already updated. And before CPU installation, I didn't update anything.
Acejavelin I saved settings three times as Power Saving Mode, Normal Mode & Optimal Mode. However, I see same message after next start.

Comment: Did you update the BIOS firmware BEFORE installing the new CPU? That's generally a highly-recommended step, especially if the CPU is newer than the one previously installed in the MB.

Comment: @user249711 - Go ahead and change the battery.

Comment: Try F10 to save the new bios configuration and reboot rather the choose a boot device.

Comment: Yes, I did same thing. In boot priority, selected HD as a first boot device and saved by pressing F10. After restart, again I see the same issue.

Comment: Did you do a CMOS clear?

Comment: If he replaced the battery, the CMOS would effectively be cleared, so as long as that's been done, the answer is effectively yes.   However, I've had an ASUS board keep overclock settings after a battery change.  @user249711, was your previous CPU overclocked?  If so, you may need to go specifically to your processor clock settings and set everything to stock for your new processor, then save and allow the machine to reboot.

Comment: was your previous CPU overclocked? No, its wasn't overclocked.